# Character Encoding Issue - UTF8 / iso-8859-1

Tags: encoding, utf-8, asp-classic

Happy New Year!

I'm using Classic ASP on my site (jimpix.co.uk). I updated it in early December to use the Bootstrap Framework, which used this in the HEAD element:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I put all user inputted content through "Server.HTMLencode"

My understanding is that this is required to remove the risk of cross site scripting.

I have done some basic testing, and found this:

1. Encoding is UTF-8
2. Put form data through "Server.HTMLencode"
3. é, è, à, ç is rendered as Ã©, Ã¨, Ã, Ã§

View Source shows the characters as:

```
&#195;&#169;, &#195;&#168;, &#195;&#160;, &#195;&#167;
```

1. Encoding is charset=iso-8859-1
2. Put form data through "Server.HTMLencode"
3. é, è, à, ç is still rendered as é, è, à, ç

View Source shows the characters as:

```
&#233;, &#232;, &#224;, &#231;
```

The problem seems to be that I can't use "Server.HTMLencode" on pages encoded as UTF-8 without the Server.HTMLencode garbling French / German / Russian / Hebrew etc.

I have tried adding this to the top of my test page:

```
Response.CodePage = 1252
Response.LCID = 1060
Response.Charset = "utf-8"
```

But it doesn't make any difference.

My test page is very simple - there are no links to databases etc. so that rules any issues with character encoding on the database etc:

```
<%
frm = Server.HTMLencode(request("body"))
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="test0001.asp" method="post">
        <p><textarea name="body" style="width:400px; height:200px;"><%=frm%></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit"></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have put the encoding back to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

On my live site for now, while I try to work this out.

Any advice would be much appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing which looks wrong in the code you have provided is that for utf-8 you should be using

```
Response.CodePage = 65001
```

1252 is for Windows-1252, which is (almost) the same as iso-8859-1

Also if your page contains any hardcoded non westerh characters then you need to save the page with utf-8 encoding.  You can do this with notepad. Select Save as from the file menu and you'll see the option in the dialogue box.

I recommend this page, which gives a bit more detail

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: Thanks John - that's fixed it :-) Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: One other little point - 2057 is the lcid setting for the UK.  1060 appears to be Slovenia.  It shouldn't make any difference though unless you are using the FormatCurrency function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx